Compilers [LR and LL parsing}
I was supposed to implement a stack machine code and I wrote a production and the code works. I am not able to understand if I have written a LL parser or an LR parser.
Can anyone take some time to help me with what I have written?
main:
| commands EOF {()}
| EOF {()}
commands:
| command SEMI commands { $1; $3 }
| command SEMI  { $1 }
| command SEMI command_prime commands { $1; $4 }
| command SEMI command_prime { $1}
command:
| PUSH INT { push $2;  }
| POP      { pop ();  }
| ADD      { add ();  }
| SUB      { sub ();  }
| MUL      { mul ();  }
| DIV      { div ();  }
| SHOW     { show ();  }
|  { failwith "Lexing error" }
command_prime:
| NEWLINE { clean();}
